# IOS UILabel Multiline in UITableViewCell

Tags: ios, uitableview, uilabel

I'm using custom UITableViewCell and I Have UILabel Inside my cell but the problem is when i'm set Text To my UILabel The text destined to top .

[image: this is my screen shot]

This Is my Code :

```
-(UITableViewCell *) tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    static NSString *simpleTableIdentifier = @"EventsTBC";

    EventsTBC *cell = (EventsTBC *)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:simpleTableIdentifier];
    if (cell == nil)
    {
        NSArray *nib = [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"EventsTBC" owner:self options:nil];
        cell = [nib objectAtIndex:0];
    }

    cell.EventText.numberOfLines = 0;
    cell.EventText.font = [self fontForCell];
    cell.EventText.textAlignment = NSTextAlignmentRight;


   // [cell.EventText setFrame:CGRectMake(-30, 30, 300, [[Tools alloc] heightForText:[[Tools alloc] warpText:[Events objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]]])];

    [cell.EventText setLineBreakMode:NSLineBreakByWordWrapping];

    cell.EventText.text = [[Tools alloc] warpText:[Events objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]];

    cell.EventText = [self sizeToMultiline:cell.EventText];

    cell.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:0 green:0 blue:0 alpha:0.10];

    return cell;
}

- (UIFont *)fontForCell
{
    return [UIFont boldSystemFontOfSize:18.0];
}

-(CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{

    //    return 150;
  return [[Tools alloc] heightForText:[[Tools alloc] warpText:[Events objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]]];

}
```

heightForText Method Gave my A height of my Text :

```
- (CGFloat)heightForText:(NSString *)bodyText
{
    UIFont *cellFont = [UIFont systemFontOfSize:17];
    CGSize constraintSize = CGSizeMake(300, MAXFLOAT);
    CGSize labelSize = [bodyText sizeWithFont:cellFont constrainedToSize:constraintSize lineBreakMode:UILineBreakModeWordWrap];
    CGFloat height = labelSize.height;
    NSLog(@"height=%f", height);
    return height;
}
```

warpText Method Replace \n With \n To make new line .

Answer (score 0):

When you print the height value, does it seem incorrect?

The sizeWithFont method was deprecated lately, and for me it stopped working.

I replaced it with something like this, thanks to another answer in this website:

```
NSAttributedString *attributedText = [[NSAttributedString alloc]
                                          initWithString:bodyText
                                          attributes:@
                                          { NSFontAttributeName: cellFont}];

CGRect rect = [attributedText boundingRectWithSize:(CGSize){300, CGFLOAT_MAX}
                                           options:NSStringDrawingUsesLineFragmentOrigin
                                           context:nil];

CGFloat height = rect.size.height;
```

Comment: thanks for your answer , but it still not working .
http://i.stack.imgur.com/dsJbu.jpg

Comment: It's hard to understand what's happening from that screenshot. When you nslog the height value, is it correct?